# How to change field in ModelForm generated html form?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I'm making one of my first django apps with sqlite database. I have some models like for example:

```
class Connection(models.Model):
    routeID = models.ForeignKey(Route, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activityStatus = models.BooleanField()
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Route(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

and forms

```
class RouteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Route
        fields = ['name']

class ConnectionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Connection
        fields = ['routeID', 'activityStatus', 'car']
```

And in my website, in the url for adding new Connection, I have cascade list containing RouteIDs. And I'd like it to contain RouteName, not ID, so it would be easier to choose. How should I change my ConnectionForm, so I could still use foreign key to Route table, but see RouteName instead of RouteID?

[For now it's looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSZz9.png), but I'd love to have list of RouteNames, while still adding to Connection table good foreign key, RouteID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the Route Model's `__str__` method:

```
class Route(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

def __str__(self):
   return self.name
```

Because the `__str__()` method is called whenever you call str() on an object. Django uses str(obj) in a number of places like in Modelform. By default it returns `id` or `pk` that is why you were seeing ids in model form. So by overriding it with `name`, you will see the names appear in choice field. Please see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#str) for more details on this.

Comment: I get it now! Thanks for help :)